# Passing Multiple variables to an application using VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am trying to path multiples variables to an application using vbscript but it is not working for me and I do not know how to fix:

```
Set SH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
  SH.Run ".\Resizer.exe /resize /overwrite /width: " & strResize & objFile.Path & objFile.Path,,True
Next
```

Resizer.exe will resize objFile.path (example: D:\pic.jpg) with strReszie width and will save it again as objFile.path

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You're not putting any spaces between your params:

   ```
   strResize & objFile.Path & objFile.Path
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   strResize & " " & objFile.Path & " " & objFile.Path
   ```
2. Make sure you surround any file paths with quotes, in case they contains spaces:

   ```
   strResize & " " & Chr(34) & objFile.Path & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & objFile.Path & Chr(34)
   ```